# What is the rule for capitalizing roles like Captain or District Attorney please in this context please?

Tags: grammar, proper-nouns, capitalization

Sentence 1:The District Attorney is coming to visit us on Wednesday.

question: Why is District Attorney capitalized as a proper noun? Is it because 'District Attorney' substitutes for a person's name whether the surrounding text reveals the person's name earlier or not? Or is it because we are referring to a specific person whether the person's name is mentioned in the surrounding text earlier or not? What is the rule/(s) please?

Answer (score 2):

You would expect a title to be capitalised when it is *unique* and you are naming that unique role.

In your example, you used 'district attorney' with the definite article, '*the*', making it unique. There may be many district attorneys, but in any specific area there will perhaps be just one, making it unique in that context.

For example:

> - He works as **a** district attorney.
> - He is **the** District Attorney

Also consider whether you are using it as a title or not. For example, lets say your job title was "Senior Writer", and that was a unique role at your workplace. Nobody else held that title; however, there are many other writers. You might say "I am *the* Senior Writer", using your full title, but you might also say "I am the senior writer", using 'senior' as an adjective and 'writer' as a non-unique name for your role. You are, in fact, saying that you are senior *among* all the writers. It is possible that "district attorney" could be used the same way, with 'district' acting as an adjective to set the position apart from other attorneys.